# Смена кодировки в Веб сервере

Tags: java, rest, wildfly

Имеется проблема с кодировкой при разработке веб приложения. Я использую веб приложение WildFly 11.0.0.

Вот мой web.xml

```
       <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >


<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>startPage</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/resources/pages/index.html</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>startPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>account</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/resources/pages/mainFrame.html</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>account</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/account</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>css</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>jpeg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Вот какая кодировка выводится в админ панеле от WildFly - UTF-8.
[image]

А вот то что я получаю на стороне клиента:
[image]

Кодировку в html страницах тоже указываю:

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>
   <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/index.css" type="text/css">-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/appcontext/resources/css/index.css" type="text/css"/> 
</head>
```

Что мне нужно сделать, что бы изменить правильно кодировку, и где ее изменить?

Comment: я в течении часа-двух подробно отпишусь по данному вопросу

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: @Михаил так  поможете ?

Comment: да...Я вчера 4 пункта написал уже в Ваш ответ..осталось два последних но у меня к сожалению времени ограниченное количество поэтому переключился немного на работу...сегодня оставшиеся 2 пункта оформлю и отправлю

Comment: Хорошо, я подожду.

Comment: @Михаил вы поможете с вопросом, или нет?